# Android Emulator: /dev/kvm not found, Vt-x supported

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, archlinux, kvm

I have both hardware virtualization and Vt-d enabled in my bios settings. By running a few other commands, like `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` I can confirm I can run it. However, android studio tells me /dev/kvm is not found. Using `sudo modprobe kvm-intel` gives me the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Input/output error
```

I'm running arch on the lastest kernel. I haven't found the cpu-checker(kvm-ok) package for the distro, but I assume it would return the same /dev/kvm not found error.

Any idea what I might have missed?

**Edit:**

dmesg output:

```
[17589.507959] kvm: CPU 0 feature inconsistency!
[17603.543922] kvm: CPU 1 feature inconsistency!
```

Comment: Intel i5 6300HQ on a laptop

Comment: It's just "a" laptop? has it a manufacturer? A model number?

Comment: MSI CX62 6QD. That's all I can get, I don't have the packaging and it's not written anywhere on it. If needed I can try and find it somewhere on amazon, but would that help that much ?

Comment: I found the laptop. The problem here is that this error is only supposed to occur on systems with two or more physical processors. Your laptop has only one. It could possibly have a defect, or your BIOS might not be up to date.

Comment: Please show the output of `dmesg | grep microcode` and add all of the previous information to your question. Comments are only temporary and that important information should not be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. When running `sudo modprobe kvm-intel` I was getting an error. When running `dmesg | grep microcode`, I got another error:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

Running `sudo pacman -S intel-ucode` fixed it. Taken from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/984971/681043), [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1724650) and [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode#Installation)

Answer (score 2):

For Arch Linux these might be the commands required:

- checking for hardware support: `LC_ALL=C lscpu | grep Virtualization`.
- checking for kernel support: `zgrep CONFIG_KVM /proc/config.gz`.
- to insert the kernel module: `modprobe kvm` & `kvm-intel`(ordinary not manually).
- try to start the service with: `systemctl start libvirtd.service`.

see the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM).

Comment: Checked everything, it's supposed to work. The only issue is with kvm-intel. I edited the question with the result from ```dmesg```